# stdin is missing for any process I pipe into which uses Windows ftype and assoc mechanism to select the correct executable

Tags: windows, pipe, stdin, file-association

I'm on WindowsXP. This seems to affect any process, but I'll use Python3.2 to demonstrate it. A script, 'filter.py':

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line)
```

Running it like this:

```
echo hello | filter.py
```

Breaks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Documents and Settings\jhartley\docs\projects\filtercwd\filter.py", line 3, in <module>
    for line in sys.stdin:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Sure enough, adding a print to discover the value of sys.stdin reports that it is None (and of NoneType.)

Alternatively, running it like this:

```
echo hello | python filter.py
```

(with an explicit invokation of python) works perfectly fine.

My .py files are hooked up to execute using Python using the assoc and ftype mechanism (the way Windows associates particular filename extensions to be executed using particular programs):

```
> assoc .py
.py=Python.File
> ftype Python.File
Python.File="F:\Python32\python.exe" "%1" %*
```

(this is the same 'python.exe' that is foremost on my path)

**Update**: This isn't a Python thing. The same thing happens if I create filter.sh, run using cygwin bash. Explicitly running 'echo hello | bash filter.sh' works fine, but 'echo hello | filter.sh' which executes filter.sh using bash via the assoc and ftype mechanism, fails with '/dev/stdin: No such file or directory'.

So I do I have to add this explicit 'python' to all my command lines? Plus, I'm curious about why it's breaking. Is it just some peculiarity of my machine, or do other people see this too?

Answer (score 1):

What `echo` are you using?  Do you have a UNIX-style `echo` utility on your path or are you just using the Microsoft one (which does not do what you want it to)?  What happens if you type `echo on` at the command prompt?

I am running in Windows 7 and was unable to reproduce this.  I have a UNIX-style `echo` utility on my path.  I have [installed ruby 1.9.2](http://rubyinstaller.org/) and written tiny program in `test.rb`:

```
while s = $stdin.gets
  print s
end
```

The program runs when I type any of these commands:

1. `test.rb`
2. `ruby test.rb`
3. `echo hello | test.rb`
4. `echo hello | ruby test.rb`

Commands 1 and 2 behave identically.  Commands 3 and 4 behave identically.  Everything behaves as I would expect.

**EDIT 1:**
Here are some commands I ran:

```
C:\Users\David\Documents\scraps\test_ruby>ls
test.rb

C:\Users\David\Documents\scraps\test_ruby>assoc .rb
File association not found for extension .rb

C:\Users\David\Documents\scraps\test_ruby>echo hi | test.rb
hi
```

I don't know much about ftype, but maybe you should install ruby on your system and see if my example program works for you.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the reponse.I'm have all the cygwin binaries foremost on my PATH, including echo. Maybe it's a WindowsXP thing. Funny I haven't noticed it before. I'll try it on other flavours of Windows and report back.

Comment: Oh! And, can I ask you to show your ftype and assoc settings that associate .rb files with ruby? Maybe I set mine up ina crazy way. i.e. what's the output of "assoc .rb" and "ftype X", where X is the output from the assoc command. Thanks!

Comment: I updated by answer to include that info.  I did my experiments in the normal Microsoft Command Prompt.  What shell are you using?

Comment: Hey. My shell is 'cmd.exe'. If you have no assoc set up for .rb files, then how does Windows7 know to run 'test.rb' with 'ruby'? Has windows started reading hashbang lines nowadays?

Comment: There is no hashbang in my test.rb so it must be something else.

Comment: Hey. So this isn't an answer to my question, but David has clearly spent time investigating the issue to try and help me out. His is the only answer. What's the social norm here, do I award him the correct answer, or do I leave the question without a chosen answer?

Comment: An upvote would at least be appreciated, but If I didn't solve your problem then you shouldn't accept it as the answer.